# how to detect already saved link in a text file

Tags: python-3.x

so i made this really simple program that saves the links i give it to a text file and i want it to tell me if i try to save a link that's already there but it won't! what am i doing wrong?

```
import os

space = " "

Links_lst = []

Links_i_saved = "Links i saved2.txt"

current_directory = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
if Links_i_saved in current_directory:
    with open(Links_i_saved, "r") as f:
        for i in f.readlines():
            if "Link: " in i:
                Links_lst.append(i.split("Link: ")[1])
            else:
                Links_lst.append(i)

while True:
    inpt = input("Give us a link (type 'break' to exit): ")
    if inpt == "break":
        break        
    else:
        if len(inpt) > 0:
            with open(Links_i_saved, "a+") as f:
                if inpt not in Links_lst:
                    if "." in inpt:
                        f.write("\n" + inpt.split(".", 2)[1] + space * (15 - len(inpt.split(".", 2)[1])) + space * 5 + "Link: " + inpt)
                    else:
                        f.write("\n" + inpt + space * (15 - len(inpt)) + space * 5 + "Link: " + inpt)
                    Links_lst.append(inpt)
                else:
                    print("You already saved this one!")
        else:
            print("No empty strings please!")
```

i want it to say "You already saved this one!" when the link already exists but it won't unless i try to save it twice with the program running (i don't want to use .read() because then it would "detect" www.google.com for example if i had any google URLs saved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to print already saved links, you will notice that the links have trailing whitespaces `\r\n` in front of them. These white spaces are causing this error.

Try this code:

```
import os

space = " "
Links_lst = []
Links_i_saved = "Links i saved2.txt"
current_directory = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

if Links_i_saved in current_directory:
    with open(Links_i_saved, "r") as f:
        for i in f.readlines():
            if "Link: " in i:
                Links_lst.append((i.split("Link: ")[1]).rstrip())
            else:
                Links_lst.append(i)

print(Links_lst)

while True:
    inpt = input("Give us a link (type 'break' to exit): ")
    if inpt == "break":
        break        
    else:
        if len(inpt) > 0:
            with open(Links_i_saved, "a+") as f:
                if inpt not in Links_lst:
                    if "." in inpt:
                        f.write("\n" + inpt.split(".", 2)[1] + space * (15 - len(inpt.split(".", 2)[1])) + space * 5 + "Link: " + inpt)
                    else:
                        f.write("\n" + inpt + space * (15 - len(inpt)) + space * 5 + "Link: " + inpt)
                    Links_lst.append(inpt)
                else:
                    print("You already saved this one!")
        else:
            print("No empty strings please!")
```